# UIView.animateWithDuration swift 3

Tags: ios, keyboard, swift3

[image]

When the button is pressed it works. After clicking this function shows another view

```
@IBAction func charSetPressed(_ button: UIButton) {
    if button.titleLabel!.text == "1/2" {

        charSet1.isHidden = true
        charSet2.isHidden = false

        button.setTitle("2/2", for: .normal)

    } else if button.titleLabel!.text == "2/2" {
        charSet1.isHidden = false
        charSet2.isHidden = true
        button.setTitle("1/2", for: .normal)
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {

        button.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2.0, 2.0)
        }, completion: {(_) -> Void in(here the error happend)

            button.transform =
            CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1, 1)
    })
}
```

Comment: what is the error and where is your error

Comment: Show me your error log

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995145/cgaffinetransformidentity-is-unavailable-in-swift for some of the new Swift3 syntax

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Tqo.png          @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 7, accepted):

//Animate on key press...  (For Swift 3.0)

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.0, y: 2.0)
    }, completion:{ _ in
        button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

## Result:

[image]

---

## Code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
  @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
  
  @IBAction func buttonTouched(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    
    // animate scaling by 2.0, 2.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
      let transformScaled = CGAffineTransform
                                          .identity
                                          .scaledBy(x: 2.0, y: 2.0)

      self.myView.transform = transformScaled
    }) { (finished) in
      // once finished first animation
      // start second animation
      if finished {
        // animate scaling by 1.0, 1.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { 
          let transformScaled = CGAffineTransform
                                              .identity
                                              .scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
          
          self.myView.transform = transformScaled
        })
      }
    }
    
  }
  
}
```