# 'CGAffineTransformIdentity' is unavailable in Swift

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Came across this error when trying to do adapt some animations into Swift3 syntax.

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, 
 initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [] , animations: {
        fromView.transform = offScreenLeft

        toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        }, completion: { finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)              
    })
```

and got this:

> 'CGAffineTransformIdentity' is unavailable in Swift

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Found this [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51438) which suggested that "The global constant was moved into a static property, and the Swift 3 migrator, as you've discovered, failed to correct for that. " and that you can simply change the code to :

```
 toView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
```

**EDIT**

or even simpler:

```
toView.transform = .identity
```

Comment: Note that the type `CGAffineTransform` can be inferred by context, so you could just say `toView.transform = .identity`